# How to delete individual cookies from Firefox in Privacy Mode?

Tags: firefox, cookies

[Firefox' official support states](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox) states that individual cookies can be deleted using the padlock at the left of the address bar or by the global Manage Data setting.

However, when Firefox is set to Never remember history then those options just aren't available. The padlock simply doesn't contain any option below Permissions, and the Manage Data is simply empty.

If you compare this to Chrome's Incognito mode, while its "All cookies and site data" setting likewise doesn't show cookies that were used in this mode, its padlock still allows deleting cookies as usual.

So how can individual cookies still be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

One way I found was deleting individual cookies through the console's Storage (although they're still visible there until the next refresh).

[image: Deleting individual cookies through Firefox' console's Storage]

Feel free to add another answer if there's an easier way.